# Why the "get_output_size" is len(alphabet) + 1 not len(alphabet) in the Keras OCR example？

Tags: keras, ocr

I am just a Keras beginner and I try to implement a OCR project by Keras.So I try to learn from Keras OCR example.Here's [a link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py)!
I do not understand why "get_output_size" in class TextImageGenerator is  len(alphabet) + 1 but not len(alphabet)?
I will appreciate it if someone can tell me why ..

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the CTC layer used as cost function. Maybe reading the scientific papers will give you more perspective, but it's related to a "extra" class used by the model to say ("there is no letter"). 
[Paper by Graves explaining the algorithm behind](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3449-offline-handwriting-recognition-with-multidimensional-recurrent-neural-networks.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is **one extra-character needed** in neural networks trained with **CTC loss**. This extra-character essentially means "no character seen at this position" and is called **CTC blank**.

It is used to allow different alignments of a text or to allow some white-space between characters (think of an image containing "    hello" or "hello    " with whitespace around them, for both you want to recognize "hello"). 
When recognizing the text, these blanks are removed: e.g. when using best path decoding, the best-scoring character at each position is taken, but the blanks will be removed.

To get a better idea of this special CTC blank character, let's look at the illustration below. The output of the neural network contains the characters a, b and the CTC blank (denoted as "-"). 
Let's pick the best-scoring characters for each position t0...t4, this gives us "aaa-b". Best path decoding removes repeated characters, this gives us "a-b", and finally removes all blanks, which gives us "ab".
[image]

If you want some more information, you can look at my [CTC article](https://towardsdatascience.com/3797e43a86c), or [this article](https://distill.pub/2017/ctc/), or the [original paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for helping me to explain this problem...I will read some paper about CTC...

Comment: @CaptainSama when someone provides an answer that is helpful or solves the issue, it is expected that you as the questioner upvote or accept, respectively. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers